# Javascript Error: 'missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, stringbuilder

I have the following `StringBuilder` and inside of it I want to append my html, I have the following code but I am getting this error: `Javascript Error: 'missing ) after argument list`

Although in stackoverflow there are dozens of question with this same title, I checked all of them and could not solve my error.

```
StringBuilder emplDiv = new StringBuilder();
emplDiv.Append("$('.ulEmployeeSearch').append('<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><p>test<p></div>')");
```

Please help me.

Comment: I think that using ' to wrap the string and use inside is not working..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because in the JS string you're creating is this:

```js
$('.ulEmployeeSearch').append('<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><p>test<p></div>')
```

You can now see from the syntax highlighting that the quotes you're using to delimit the string are the same as those wrapping the attribute values - hence the error. You need to escape the inner quotes:

```
emplDiv.Append("$('.ulEmployeeSearch').append('<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12\"><p>test<p></div>')");
```

Comment: Thanks make You solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are having single quotes inside the class attribute which makes the missing argument issue, fix this like below-

```
StringBuilder emplDiv = new StringBuilder();
emplDiv.Append("$('.ulEmployeeSearch').append('<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12\"><p>test<p></div>')");
```

Answer (score 2):

you have not added the closing tag of paragraph. try to use below code.

```
emplDiv.Append("$('.ulEmployeeSearch').append('<div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12\"><p>test</p></div>')");
```